# Java string.split vs. C# Regex.split - limit to certain number of fields

Tags: java, c#, regex, split

I am a Java developer, but am working on a C# project. What I need to do is split a String by a delimiter, but limit it to a certain number of fields. In Java, I can do this:

```
String message = "xx/xx - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx - xxxxxxx";
String[] splitMessage = message.split("\\s-", 3);
```

In this case, it will split it by the `-`, but I want to also have it check for any space before the dash, and limit it to 3 fields of the String. The String coming through is broken down into `___ - ____________ - _________` with the first space being a date (like `12/31`) the second space being a message about the string, and the third space being a location tied to the message. The reason I limit it to 3 fields so the array **only** has 3 elements. The reason I do this is because sometimes the message can have dashes in it to look like this: `12/31 - Test message - test - Test City, 11111`. So my Java code above would split it into this:

```
0: 12/31
1: Test message - test
2: Test City, 11111
```

I am trying to achieve something similar in C#, but am not sure how to limit it to a certain number of fields. This is my C# code:

```
var splitMessage = Regex.Split(Message, " -");
```

The problem is that without a limit, it splits it into 4 or 5 fields, instead of just the 3. For example, if this were the message: `12/31 - My test - don't use - just a test - Test City, 11111`, it would return a string[] with 5 indexes:

```
0: 12/31
1: My test
2: don't use
3: just a test
4: Test City, 11111
```

When I want it to return this:

```
0: 12/31
1: My test - don't use - just a test
2: Test City, 11111
```

Before you ask, I can't change the incoming String. I have to parse it the same why I did in Java. So is there an equivalent to limiting it to 3 fields? Is there a better way to do it besides using `Regex.Split()`?

Comment: If you want `["12/31","My test - don't use - just a test", "Test City, 11111"]` the [`Regex.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Split_System_String_System_Int32_System_Int32_) *count* argument won't do because it will be splitting at each match from left to right.

Comment: Try `var m = Regex.Match(text, @"^([^-]*)(?: - (.*?))?(?: - ([^-]*))?$")` and check `m.Groups[1].Value`, `m.Groups[2].Value` and `m.Groups[3].Value`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/b8cogu/1).

Comment: Even using Java’s `message.split("\\s-", 3)` will not give you the result you describe.  I would suggest foregoing regular expressions and simply using `message.indexOf(" -")` and `message.lastIndexOf(" -")`, then using three message.substring calls.

Comment: @VGR Yes it will, I have this working in my code, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to split based on the first and last instance of `-`, such that you get exactly three fields (so long as there are at least two dashes in the string), C# does actually have a neat trick for this. C# Regex allows for non-fixed-width lookbehinds. So the following regex:

```
(?<=^[^-]*)-|-(?=[^-]*$)

(<=      //start lookbehind
   ^     //look for start of string
   [^-]* //followed by any amount of non-dash characters
)        //end lookbehind
-        //match the dash
|        //OR
-        //match a dash
(?=      //lookahead for
   [^-]* //any amount of non-dash characters
   $     //then the end of the string
)        //end lookahead
```

Will match the first and last dash, and allow you to split the string the way you want to.

```
var splitMessage = Regex.Split(Message, "(?<=^[^-]*)-|-(?=[^-]*$)");
```

Note that this also has no problem splitting into fewer than three groups, if there are less dashes, but will not split into more than three.

Comment: This is good, I posted a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60102694/java-string-split-vs-c-sharp-regex-split-limit-to-certain-number-of-fields#comment106300371_60102694) with a similar matching approach, but I wonder if the multicharacter delimiter support is required.  A negated character class won't do then.

Comment: That's true, but it wouldn't be terribly difficult to change it to something like `(?:(?!delim1|delim2).)*` if we needed multiple delimiters. But Anyways, hey! Thanks for your recommendations on my last answer :)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for - I just suck at Regex in general, so I had no idea how to get this doing what I wanted to. I appreciate it!

Comment: @WitchKing17 No problem! I love regex, these are always fun little challenges! Glad I could help :)

Comment: @ZaelinGoodman, hmmm it looks like this is still just a tad bit off. Could you make it so only catches dashes with a white space before? Because sometimes I get a message that looks like this: `test -test` instead of `test - test`, it's splitting it correctly, just sometimes splitting it at the wrong spot.

Comment: Sure, do you want it to always have to have a whitespace before, or do you want it to always have to have a whitespace before and after?  Could you provide an example of a string you want this rule for, and what the split should look like? Shouldn't be too difficult, just want to get it right :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't split like with the delimiter inside the one of the desired grouped, except when that is the last group.

You can however use a custom regex that consume as much as possible in the 2nd group to parse the said input:

```
var splitMessage = Regex.Match("12/31 - Test message - test - Test City, 11111", "^(.+?) - (.+) - (.+)$")
    .Groups
    .Cast<Group>()
    // skip first group which is the entire match
    .Skip(1)
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

Given that the first group is "xx/xx", you can also opt to use this regex instead:

```
"^(../..) - (.+) - (.+)$"
// or, assuming they are date
"^(\d{2}/\d{2}) - (.+) - (.+)$"
```

---

EDIT: Or, you can just split by " - ", and then concatenate everything in the middle together when there is more than 3 matches:

```
var groups = "12/31 - Test message - test - Test City, 11111".Split(new[] { " - " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
if (groups.Length > 3)
{
    groups = new[]
    {
        groups[0],
        string.Join(" - ", groups.Skip(1).Take(groups.Length - 2)),
        groups[groups.Length - 1]
    };
}
```

Comment: Your regex requires at least two `-` delimiters, so if a string has 0 or 1 delimiter occurrences it won't find a match.

Answer (score -1):

Whe I have to split a string at certain delimiters including optional spaces, I do it usually this way:

```
String message = "xx/xx - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx - xxxxxxx";
String[] splitMessage = message.split(" *- *", 3);    
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(splitMessage));
```

Outputs: [xx/xx, xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, xxxxxxx]

```
String message = "12/31 - My test - don't use - just a test - Test City; 11111";
String[] splitMessage = message.split(" *- *", 3);    
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(splitMessage));
```

Outputs: [12/31, My test, don't use - just a test - Test City; 11111]

But you seem to want that something different:

```
splitMessage[0] shall contain the first part
splitMessage[1] shall contain the second and third part
splitMessage[2] shall contain the rest
```

How do you want to tell your computer that the second output element shall contain two parts? I think this is impossible except by splitting the string into all 5 parts and then re-concatenating the parts together as you want.

Maybe it's not clear what result you want. Can you specify the requirement more clearly: What shall happen if the input string contains more than 3 elements?

Comment: Asking clarifying questions should be done in the comments to the question, not posted as an answer.